# What exactly does this random.uniform line in Python do?

Tags: python, random, random-forest

I'm following a [tutorial here from Andrew Cross](http://www.agcross.com/2015/02/random-forests-in-python-with-scikit-learn/) on using random forests in Python. I got the code to run fine, and for the most part I understand the output. However, I am unsure on exactly what this line does:

```
df['is_train'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, len(df)) <= .75
```

I know that it "creates a (random) uniform distribution between 0 and 1 and assigns 3/4ths of the data to be in the training subset." However, the training subset is not always exactly 3/4 of the subset. Sometimes it is smaller and sometimes it is larger. So is a random sized subset chosen that is approximately 75%? Why not make it always 75%?

Comment: Because the numbers aren't always *perfectly, evenly* distributed (and being distributed randomly there is some deviation that can occur even though the random data will have a uniform distribution). Furthermore, the exact '75%' divide would not be possible for all lengths anyway: say there are 9 - how do you choose 3/4 of that, under any distribution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`np.random.uniform(0, 1, len(df))` creates an array of `len(df)` random numbers.
`<= .75` then creates another array containing `True` where the numbers matched that condition, and `False` in other places.
The code then uses the data in indexes where `True` was found. Since the random distribution is... well, random, you won't get exactly 75% of the values.

Answer (score 4):

It does not assign `3/4`ths of the data to be in the training subset.
It assigns the probability that data is in the training subset to be `3/4`:

Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> sum(np.random.uniform(0, 1, 10) < .75)
8
>>> sum(np.random.uniform(0, 1, 10) < .75)
10
>>> sum(np.random.uniform(0, 1, 10) < .75)
7
```

- 80% of the data is in the training subset in the 1st example
- 100% -- in the 2nd one
- 70%  -- in the 3rd.

On average, it should be 75%.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be more strict selecting randomly a training set always very near to 75%, you can use some code like this:

```
d = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 1000)
p = np.percentile(d, 75)

print(np.sum(d <= p))   # 750
print(np.sum(d <= .75)) # 745
```

In your example:

```
d = np.random.uniform(0, 1, len(df))
p = np.percentile(d, 75)
df['is_train'] = d <= p
```